# Dry insert to check for index collisions

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I check whether insertion will result in UNIQUE INDEX collision error without actually inserting something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run a SELECT query with unique column condition and if result data set isn't empty, it means will occur unique index error:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE unique_column = 'new_insert_value' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I think "down voter" think the other answer (with catch error) is correct and i misunderstand your question. But i don't think so. You ask check if any record with new data **before** insert. Maybe you need a username check senario and want give feedback visitor that username token before or not.

Answer (score 4):

`INSERT` and catch the error. Is cheapest way, because it performs the lookup and actually does the insert on success. The problem with a separate check before the actual INSERT is, of course, concurrency. Multiple processes can do the check, all conclude that there will be no collision, and all decide to `INSERT`, only to collide. Getting this scenario right (check then insert) is so problematic (locking an non-existing slot) that is really not worth.

MySQL has syntax to gracefully handle collision [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Comment: Not exactly what I need. Data generation is very time-consuming and I want to check if it is present before generation process. In my case its better first to check if data exist, then generate them and then do INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE as you say.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to do INSERT and rollback it at once.